# What's the difference between an explicit call and an implicit call of the conversion function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example:

```cpp
struct A{
    template<class T>
    operator T();  // #1
};
struct B:A{
    template<class U>
    operator U&&();  // #2
};
int main(){
  B  b;
  int a = b;  // #3
  b.operator int();  // #4
}
```

According to [class.member.lookup] p7

> If N is a non-dependent conversion-function-id, conversion function templates that are members of T are considered. For each such template F, the lookup set
> `S(t,T)` is constructed, considering a function template declaration to have the name `t` only if it corresponds to a declaration of F ([basic.scope.scope]). The members of the declaration set of each such lookup set, which shall not be an invalid set, are included in the result.

`#1` and `#2` are both included in the lookup result regardless of what the *conversion-function-id*s are in `#3` and `#4`. The [diagnosis](https://godbolt.org/z/8rdj6Eorz) for `#3` is what we expect, in other words, both `#1` and `#2` are candidates and they are indistinguishable.

However, it seems that [implementations](https://godbolt.org/z/e613rPaoY) only consider `#2` as the unique candidate when processing `#4`. As said above, the candidate set should be the same for either `#3` or `#4`. Do I omit some other rules that cause the difference? Or, Is it a bug in implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementations just haven’t caught up to the new(ly clarified) rules, which had to be largely invented in 2020 since no published standard version has ever described lookup for conversion function templates in any sensible way.

Comment: Thanks. For the concept: two declarations correspond, I think it is a bit unclear for conversion function templates(i.e. *conversion-function-id* is not a name).

Comment: @xmh0511: [basic.pre]/4 begs to differ.

Comment: I have my glasses reversed...  One more thing is to determine whether their return types and non-object-parameter-type-lists are equivalent, depending on [temp.over.link]? `When determining whether types or type-constraints are equivalent, the rules above are used to compare expressions involving template parameters.` However, `T` and `U&&` are not expressions anyway.

Comment: @xmh0511: [temp.over.link] needs work, yes.  It doesn’t even address basic things like repeating `template<class T,class U> void f(decltype(T/*U*/::foo));` with the comment substituted.